# Pip returns nothing in Windows command line

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation, pip

Pip command returns nothing. I enter $ pip [command] and all I get back is a new line without any instructions running.

Input:

```
C:/Python34/Scripts> pip
```

Result:

```
C:/Python34/Scripts>
```

I have tried $ pip --verbose - same result. Nothing works. I have correctly placed Python34 and Scripts folder in the Path.

> %CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Roxio
>   Shared\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts

Python runs fine in command line.

- Windows 7 SP1 64-bit
- Python 3.4
- Running Command Prompt as Administrator

Please help :(

Comment: Are you actually running a pip command, or just calling 'pip'? Try running pip -h to get a list of commands. If that also just returns a newline, I'd imagine your pip install is not complete or correct.

Comment: As I stated before, I ran pip [command] -- doesn't matter what pip command I enter -- the result is the same. How could I have a bad installation of pip? I installed Python 3.4 yesterday on this machine.

Comment: Can you try running pip through python, instead of as a stand-alone? Try running from C:\Python34 the command python -m pip -V to see if that returns a pip version number.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I receive: "pip 7.1.0 from C:\Python34\lib\site-packages <pythong 3.4>"

Comment: OK, so it looks like pip is working through Python, and you've got the correct version. While I don't know why you're getting a blank line (maybe someone else can answer that?) it looks like you can install anything you need to through pip using the python -m pip -install SomePackage command. Hopefully that is at least some help to you!

Comment: Lol nope. "No module named -install" is what I get back trying to do that.

Comment: I have almost the same set up as you and pip works for me. There's a `pip.exe` in my `C:\Python3\Scripts` directory and that folder name is included in the contents of my `PATH` environment variable. That should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks! But as you see in my post, that's exactly what I have.

Comment: You should be able to run `py -3.4 -m pip install some_package` without any directory added to `PATH`. As to your pip.exe, something is clearly wrong but without a debugger such as windbg or cdb you'll be hard pressed to diagnose the problem.

Comment: This command worked!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hey for anyone who is having trouble getting the code that worked for Antonio to run in Python 3.5 run the following `python -m pip install some_package`

I had the same problem as antonio so changing the code to the above worked for me.